# Event not firing inside Chrome Extension using JQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am a bit new to JavaScript, and I'm having trouble catching events in a Chrome Extension I'm developing.

Here is the HTML snippet:

```
<div id="tabs-2">
    <div id="divIncome">
        <label for="box1">Label1</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="box1" />
        </div>
        <label for="box2">Label2</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="box2" />
        </div>
        <label for="box3">Label3</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="box3" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="button waves-effect" id="btnAddBox">Add Box</button><br />
    <div id="totalBox"></div>
</div>
```

The button in code above triggers an event that adds rows of input values, and also shows a delete icon. This works fine.

My desired effect is to have the user be able to click the delete icon and remove the row, but I can't get the event to trigger when the user clicks the icon. I have tried selecting using the class, name, and what feels like every possible method, but nothing works.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
$(function () {

    // WORKING
    $("#btnAddIncome").on("click",
        function (e) {
            var $newOtherIncome = $("<label for='newBox'>New Label</label><div><span><input type='text' id='newBox' style='width:95%' /></span><span style='float:right' class='delete' id='delete'><i class='material-icons delete' style='font-size:20px;'>delete</i></span>");

            $("#divIncome").append($newOtherIncome);
        });

    // NOT FIRING
    $("#delete").on("click",
        function(e) {
            alert(e.type);
        });

    // NOT FIRING
    $(".delete").on("click",
        function(e) {
            alert(e.type);
        });

}
);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are attaching your click handlers to the delete buttons before the delete button is created. You should add the handlers after the buttons are created.

Comment: I don't see elements that `class` or `id` attributes contain *delete* string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `class` **delete** not an `ID`

In this part of your code that you are appending on your `#divIncome`:

```
<label for='newBox'>New Label</label>
<div>
    <span>
        <input type='text' id='newBox' style='width:95%' />
    </span>
    <span style='float:right' class='delete' id='delete'>
       <i class='material-icons delete' style='font-size:20px;'>delete</i>
    </span>
```

You are using `delete` as class on both `<span>` and `<i>` element's
Just trigger they like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
     //Do your stuff
});
```

And when using dynamic generated elements, is important to trigger their events using `$(document).on()`, otherwise it will not be triggered

See more  [W33 Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [JQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: brilliant! that's the answer... `$(document).on()` was the missing piece.

Comment: Remember just to use `#element` on the `id` property, and `.someClass` on the `class` property ;)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in above answer you have implemented [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method in a wrong way. Here I have little improvement on your code. Its best practice to search element based on nearer selector instead of search on whole `document`. Here in the following code I have searched `.delete` class with in a `div` having id `divIncome`. It is secure and faster instead of `document` .

```js
$(function () {

    // WORKING
    $("#btnAddBox").on("click",
        function (e) {
            var $newOtherIncome = $("<div class='newBoxParent'><label for='newBox'>New Label</label><div><span><input type='text' id='newBox' style='width:95%' /></span><button style='float:right' class='delete' id='delete'><i class='material-icons delete' style='font-size:20px;'>delete</i></button></div>");

            $("#divIncome").append($newOtherIncome);
            
        });

    // NOT FIRING
    $("#divIncome").on("click",'.delete',
        function(e) {
            $(this).parents('.newBoxParent').remove();
        });
        
        // NOT FIRING
    
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <div id="divIncome">
        <label for="box1">Label1</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="box1" />
        </div>
        <label for="box2">Label2</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="box2" />
        </div>
        <label for="box3">Label3</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="box3" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="button waves-effect" id="btnAddBox">Add Box</button><br />
    <div id="totalBox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: question... on this line: `$(this).parents('.newBoxParent').remove()`... will this work if user adds multiple rows? or will it delete all of them at once?

Comment: right now, i'm using this... `$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();`

Comment: `$(this).parents('.newBoxParent').remove()` will remove the parent div with class `newBoxParent` of button with class `delete`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function () {

// WORKING
$("#btnAddBox").on("click",
    function (e) {
        var $newOtherIncome = $("<label for='newBox'>New Label</label><div><span><input type='text' id='newBox' style='width:95%' /></span><span style='float:right' class='delete' id='delete'><i class='material-icons delete' style='font-size:20px;'>delete</i></span>");

        $("#divIncome").append($newOtherIncome);
    });

$(document).on("click", ".delete"
    function(e) {
        alert(e.type);
    });

 }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding DOM dynamically to the document. All the listeners that you have added in the beginning won't work for the new ones. For this case jQuery uses the document or the parent where it is going to be added to set the listener as`$(document).on('click','selector',callBack);` [Jquery .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) In your case the selector is `.delete`. I have added the delete functionality which you can see in the following snippet

```js
$(function () {

    // WORKING
    $("#btnAddBox").on("click",
        function (e) {
            var $newOtherIncome = $("<div class='newBoxParent'><label for='newBox'>New Label</label><div><span><input type='text' id='newBox' style='width:95%' /></span><button style='float:right' class='delete' id='delete'><i class='material-icons delete' style='font-size:20px;'>delete</i></button></div>");

            $("#divIncome").append($newOtherIncome);
            
        });

    // NOT FIRING
    $(document).on("click",'.delete',
        function(e) {
            $(this).parents('.newBoxParent').remove();
        });

   
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <div id="divIncome">
        <label for="box1">Label1</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="box1" />
        </div>
        <label for="box2">Label2</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="box2" />
        </div>
        <label for="box3">Label3</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="box3" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="button waves-effect" id="btnAddBox">Add Box</button><br />
    <div id="totalBox"></div>
</div>
```